# stability estimate for the Helmholtz equation using Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Given the following problem on a square domain $\Omega$

$$
\begin{align}
  -\Delta u - \kappa^2 u &= f \quad \text{in } \Omega, \\
  u &= 0 \quad \text{ on } \partial\Omega,
 \end{align}
$$

where $\kappa>0$. The weak formulation is to find $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$
b(u,v) = (f,v) \quad \forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega)
$$
where
$$
b(u,v) = \int_\Omega (\nabla u \nabla v - \kappa^2 ) dx.
$$
I'm looking to see if there is any kind of reference to the assumption that for any $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, the problem has a unique solution $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and there exists a $C_\text{Stab} > 0$  such that

$$
\|u\|_\kappa \le C_\text{Stab} \|f\|
$$
where
$$
\|u\|_\kappa^2 = \|\nabla u \|^2 + \kappa \|\nabla u \|^2.
$$
I'm not exactly certain that such an assumption is even possible with Dirichlet boundary conditions. The only references I can find are using mixed boundary conditions, or some form of scattering problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\kappa^2$ is a Dirichlet eigenvalue for $\Delta$, there will be no uniqueness. For example if $f=0$, then you get the trivial solution and the eigenfunction corresponding to $\kappa^2$ (see also [Fredholm alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_alternative#Elliptic_partial_differential_equations)).

For other $\kappa^2$ you can use the resolvent, i.e., the inverse of $(-\Delta - \kappa^2)$ to solve the equation. The resolvent is a bounded operator and there are some generic bounds for its norm in terms of the distance to the spectrum, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784511/relation-between-the-distance-from-a-point-to-the-resolvent-set-of-a-self-adjoin).

This is also discussed in Evans' book on PDEs, page 305.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I feared is probably the case. I think the assumption works for general elliptic indefinite and non-self adjoint problems, but not so much for Helmholtz. What if the problem was set as $div (A \nabla u) - \kappa^2u =f$? Where $A$ is SPD? I'm trying to adapt some theory that was applied to the general elliptic PDE, but using a more complex scenario applied to Helmhotlz. Trying to use the same asumption seemed like a good way of ensuring a unique solution for the problem. What if $\kappa^2 = c(x)$ where $c(x) \in L^\infty(\Omega)$? Thanks for the help.